# Array of functions in C, with void pointer argument, dinamically alocated

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures

I can't declare how to properly declare a function vector that I can pass as an argument to the get_operations function, then I can call the 8 functions with the help of the components of my previously declared vector. Here is the structures I used and the functions:

```
void get_operations(void **operations) {
    operations[0] = tire_pressure_status;
    operations[1] = tire_temperature_status;
    operations[2] = tire_wear_level_status;
    operations[3] = tire_performance_score;
    operations[4] = pmu_compute_power;
    operations[5] = pmu_regenerate_energy;
    operations[6] = pmu_get_energy_usage;
    operations[7] = pmu_is_battery_healthy;
}
```

Comment: tire_pressure_status, tire_temperature_status, etc are functions that I defined in a file separated to the main.c. I want to use these function with the help of this function vector.

Comment: I suggest you reduce this to a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with only two functions from which you create a function array.

Comment: I reduced a lot! I really dont know how to handle with this problem!

Comment: You reduced it so far that you don't even show how the function is called. The MRE is supposed to be **complete**.

Comment: “Minimal Reproducible Example” does not mean “Minimal Example.” It has to be reproducible. You should not reduce it past the point where it is reproducible. Show the code that creates the array and passes it to `get_operations`.

Comment: I try this: typedef void (**FunctionPtr);
               FunctionPtr functions;   functions[0](tire_data); and I get this error : Called object type 'void (*)' is not a function or function pointer

Comment: Hello, please edit the question to include the information, but can you please expand it to show the *whole* of your minimal program. You might like to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef int (*statfunc)(void *);

int tire_pressure_status(void *);
int tire_temperature_status(void *);
int tire_wear_level_status(void *);
int tire_performance_score(void *);

void get_operations(void **operations) {
    statfunc *vect = *operations;
    vect[0] = tire_pressure_status;
    vect[1] = tire_temperature_status;
    vect[2] = tire_wear_level_status;
    vect[3] = tire_performance_score;
}

int main(void)
{
    statfunc vector[4];
    void *ptr_to_vector = vector;

    get_operations(&ptr_to_vector);

    vector[0](NULL);
    vector[1](NULL);
    vector[2](NULL);
    vector[3](NULL);
}


int tire_pressure_status(void *)
{
    return printf("%s\n", __func__);
}

int tire_temperature_status(void *)
{
    return printf("%s\n", __func__);
}

int tire_wear_level_status(void *)
{
    return printf("%s\n", __func__);
}

int tire_performance_score(void *)
{
    return printf("%s\n", __func__);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1nTPKd8v1